# Message and Key Security

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure

I'm reading [Post-Quantum Cryptography](http://www.e-reading.bz/bookreader.php/135832/Post_Quantum_Cryptography.pdf), and in the page 106 in the beginning of the Section 3 it says:

> In this section we consider the message security (opposed to key security) of
>   code-based cryptosystems ....

What's do *Message Security* and *Key Security* mean? What's a difference between those?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing without having read the book - but my guess is "Message Security" is how hard it is to figure out the plaintext when you just have the ciphertext, and "Key Security" is how hard it is to figure out the encryption key (when you have the ciphertext, and may or may not have the plaintext).  It's conceivable that it could be easier to decrypt a message without knowing the encryption key than it would be to figure out what the encryption key was.